# How To Make A UIButton Match My NavBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors, uibutton

I have a custom color navbar using the following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

I want to make a UIButton with the exact same color and gradient that the navbar is.  I've tried in photoshop but don't know how to make the 2 tone graident style.

Is there anyway to do this programatically?  I already have the buttons set up in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/). There you can find a class that extends UIButton, so that you can change the color of your buttons and even do some gradient.